# fullCalendar doesn't render inside a bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fullcalendar, bootstrap-5

Actually I'm trying to render fullCalendar inside a bootstrap tab, it works if the fullCalendar is in the active tab (generally first), but when i put it in another tab, and this is not active, when the page load calendar renders badly (I attached some images to show it).

[`Active tab is "Información básica", when i tab the "Calendario" appears that`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PM1Cm.png)

I tried to do this:

```
$('#mytabcalendar').click(function () {
     calendar.updateSize();
});
```

where "mytabcalendar" is my tab "Calendar". Thanks for any ideas

Comment: Hook to the [`shown.bs.tab`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs-tabs/#events) event for the require tab and initialise the calendar within that event handler

Comment: I tried that to, but the problem is fullcalendar is in partial page because is used in differents pages so this is render in a separete js file. also i tried put **calendar.render();** when tab pane is active and nothing :(

Answer (score 1):

When showing a new tab, You will need to the [Events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/navs-tabs/#events) fire. Something like below.:

```
var triggerTabList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('a[data-bs-toggle="tab"]'))
triggerTabList.forEach(function (triggerEl) {
  var tabTrigger = new bootstrap.Tab(triggerEl)
  triggerEl.addEventListener('hidden.bs.tab', function (event) {

    calendar.updateSize();

  })
})
```